# add value from text field to look up field crm plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

thank first all to helping me, out
I have got a big problem
I trying to run a post operation plugin in crm 2013
I have got, to Entities One is "account" and the other one is "sales"
My problem is :
The filed in entities account is lookup filed
And the filed in sales is text filed
The value from the sales Test filed I have to add in the look up filed
I have allready retrieve the value from the sales test field 
Only problem is I can’t add the value in the look up:
get an error message.

Comment: Could you please provide code that you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be appreciated if you can share the error message which you are getting.

Assuming that you are trying to set the primary contact for the account, I would have coded as follows,

Entity account=new Entity("account");
account.Id=;
account["primarycontactid"]=new EntityReference("contact",);
service.Update(account);

In this case i again assume the text value which you have retrieved is a Guid value. If not, get that value from CRM using a service.Retrive() or service.RetrieveMultiple() methods and do it as above.

Hope this helps!!!.